# How do I configure FTP accounts for vsftpd?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have a new 12.04 Desktop installation. This PC is also my server (LAMP + postgres). I have just ONE user for the OS. There are 3 PCs in my LAN.

I have installed vsFTP and that's it.

What I want to ...

I want to create 10 FTP accounts for different users and each one should have write permissions to a sub-folder in /var/www. Please note that there is only one user account for the OS.

there are many posts on working with FTP but nothing seem to address this issue of many FTP accounts for a computer that only has a single OS user defined.

This is more like what we do with cpanel. I just create different ftp accounts for different users but they're not server users. At least that's what I figured.

Any guidelines on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try on this link.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd

Solution for you is creation of virtual user. Also you can chroot them witch mean that user can not go to another folder ...

Comment: Thanks for your input. The link you gave seems promising but it's (IMO) VERY incomplete. It goes about saying edit this line and that but it doesn't say WHERE those lines are to be edited. And it says to create a virtual user I must look in the pat /etc/vsftpd but I cannot find this path. Could you help out?

Comment: path: /etc/vsftpd.conf

Comment: You can create dir vsftpd in etc

Comment: You can create dir vsftpd in /etc with commans 'sudo mkdir /etc/vsftpd' and put files. I find one more link for vsftpd configuration http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293. When create dir you must change path in /etc/vsftpd.conf

Comment: +1 for your directions. the answer is not complete but it gave me a very important element to know - the virtual user. Thanks!

Comment: Here's where I found the EXACT steps on how to do this: http://www.sigerr.org/linux/setup-vsftpd-custom-multiple-directories-users-accounts-ubuntu-step-by-step

Comment: Great. Create wiki or something. I will bookmark page.